# Autopostback is not working for the first time in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am using 5 radiobuttons in Update panel, but when i checked first time radiobutton then its not going to its checked changed. and after that means checked second time its working fine, so please tell what should be the problem.
here is my code

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>
       <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtn_A" runat="server" GroupName="rbt" 
            AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="rbtn_A_CheckedChanged" />
       <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtn_B" runat="server" GroupName="rbt" AutoPostBack="true"
            OnCheckedChanged="rbtn_B_CheckedChanged" />
       <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtn_C" runat="server" GroupName="rbt" AutoPostBack="true" 
            OnCheckedChanged="rbtn_C_CheckedChanged" />
       <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtn_D" runat="server" GroupName="rbt" AutoPostBack="true" 
            OnCheckedChanged="rbtn_D_CheckedChanged" />
   </ContentTemplate>
```

here is my first radio button c# function:
         protected void rbtn_A_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {

```
        foreach (GridViewRow gv in dl_ques.Rows)
        {
            Label lblTest = (Label)gv.FindControl("lbltest");
            Label lbl = (Label)gv.FindControl("lbl_qno");
            RadioButton rbtn_A = (RadioButton)gv.FindControl("rbtn_A");
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds = getAnswer();
            SqlCommand cmd1 = DataManager.getCommandSp("spGetIBPSTestQues");
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Test_id", Convert.ToInt32(lblTest.Text));
            DataSet dsorg = DataManager.getDataSet(cmd1);
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd = DataManager.getCommandSp("SpUpdateIBPSTestSolved");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_id", Convert.ToInt32(ht["UId"]));

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ans", "A");
                foreach (DataRow dr in dsorg.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(lbl.Text) == Convert.ToInt32(dr["actual_que"]))
                    {
                        if (dr["actual_ans"].ToString() == "A")
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ans_correct", "Yes");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ans_correct", "No");
                        }
                    }
                }
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@test_id", Convert.ToInt32(lblTest.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Test_dt", DateTime.Now);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ques_id", lbl.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastTimeMin", timehdnmin.Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastTimeSec", timehdnsec.Value);

                DataManager.WriteToDb(cmd);

            }
            else
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd = DataManager.getCommandSp("SpInsertIBPSTestSolved");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_id", Convert.ToInt32(ht["UId"]));

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ans", "A");
                foreach (DataRow dr in dsorg.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(lbl.Text) == Convert.ToInt32(dr["actual_que"]))
                    {
                        if (dr["actual_ans"].ToString() == "A")
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ans_correct", "Yes");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ans_correct", "No");
                        }
                    }
                }

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@test_id", Convert.ToInt32(lblTest.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Test_dt", DateTime.Now);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ques_id", lbl.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastTimeMin", timehdnmin.Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastTimeSec", timehdnsec.Value);

                DataManager.WriteToDb(cmd);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: but subsequently, everything works?

Comment: i am using these radio buttons in grid view. but having problem with first time. i checked everything but don't understand what is the problem.

Comment: Please show your rbtn_A_CheckChanged function

Comment: Have you placed breakpoint on checked changed event and see whether it triggers?

Comment: Alot could affect your codes. Have you checked client side functions (if you have one)

Comment: problem is its not going on Checked changed event and i don't have any client side function related to radiobuttons

Comment: is that update panel inside another update panel?

Comment: no i am using single update panel : c0dem0nkey

Comment: Have you tried putting a break point right at the start of `rbtn_A_CheckedChanged`?

Comment: Your UpdatePanel cause problem. Remove the updatePanel for catching the issue. If it causes problem then you have to add trigger in it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make one of the radio button `checked` true on page load by default

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rbtn_A" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" GroupName="rbt"
OnCheckedChanged="rbtn_A_CheckedChanged" Checked="True" />
```

Based on what you said try with this

```
if(!Page.IsPostback)
{
  rbtn_A.Checked = true;
}
```

Comment: according to my functionality i can't do this because its online examination related and i need to all checked false

Comment: if i checked any radio button first time its not going breakpoint on checked changed event. but second time its working fine going to relevant checked

Comment: these radio buttons in grid view

Comment: its not related to rbtn_A. user can checked any radio button first time. rbtn_A,B,C,D. because first time its not going on breakpoint on any checked changed event but second time working

Comment: appreciate for helping me

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but hopefully this will help someone else.

For me, it wasn’t what was happening on the page, it was how I got to the page.

I was navigating to the page using `Server.Transfer("~/MyPage.aspx");`.

Changing to `Response.Redirect("~/MyPage.aspx");` solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Set all radio button to `Checked=False;` may be it will help you

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
 <ContentTemplate>
   <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtn_A" runat="server" GroupName="rbt" 
        AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="rbtn_A_CheckedChanged" Checked="False" />
   <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtn_B" runat="server" GroupName="rbt" AutoPostBack="true"
        OnCheckedChanged="rbtn_B_CheckedChanged" Checked="False"/>
   <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtn_C" runat="server" GroupName="rbt" AutoPostBack="true" 
        OnCheckedChanged="rbtn_C_CheckedChanged" Checked="False"/>
   <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtn_D" runat="server" GroupName="rbt" AutoPostBack="true" 
        OnCheckedChanged="rbtn_D_CheckedChanged" Checked="False"/>
 </ContentTemplate>
```